# memory leak of java process

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

[root@TJHY251-103 ~]# java -version

java version "1.6.0_39"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

jvm args：

```
-Xmx4g -Xms4g -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xss256K
```

top info:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                    
12594 root      25   0 10.3g 7.5g 4764 S 23.6 95.6  71:37.33 java
```

direct mem used:

```
345.664551 MB
```

gperftools result:

```
Total: 3169.2 MB 


3147.6  99.3%  99.3%   3147.6  99.3% os::malloc 
    12.7   0.4%  99.7%     12.7   0.4% ObjectSynchronizer::omAlloc 
     4.6   0.1%  99.9%      4.6   0.1% zcalloc 
     3.0   0.1% 100.0%      3.0   0.1% init 
     0.5   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.0% readCEN 
     0.3   0.0% 100.0%      0.3   0.0% _dl_allocate_tls 
     0.1   0.0% 100.0%      0.1   0.0% instanceKlass::add_dependent_nmethod 
     0.1   0.0% 100.0%      0.1   0.0% pthread_cond_wait@GLIBC_2.2.5 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      3.9   0.1% Thread::Thread 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% pthread_cond_timedwait@GLIBC_2.2.5 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% allocZip 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% _dl_new_object 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% addMetaName 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      4.6   0.1% Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_init 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% pthread_cond_signal@GLIBC_2.2.5 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% newEntry 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% strdup 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% _nl_intern_locale_data 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% growMetaNames 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% JLI_MemAlloc 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% _dl_check_map_versions 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% _dl_map_object_deps 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% getpwuid 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% __fopen_internal 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% _dl_scope_free 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% dl_open_worker 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% initLoopbackRoutes 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% os::format_boot_path 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% os::strdup 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% __tzfile_read 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% new_composite_name 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% add_to_global 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% os::realloc 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% _nl_load_locale_from_archive 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% expand_dynamic_string_token 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% __tzstring 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%     24.9   0.8% 0x00002aaaab08d44d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%     10.8   0.3% 0x00002aaaab092859 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09289e 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      8.4   0.3% 0x00002aaaab092928 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.1   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09296d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      5.1   0.2% 0x00002aaaab0929b2 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0929f7 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab092a3c 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%     25.7   0.8% 0x00002aaaab092a81 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.2   0.0% 0x00002aaaab092d33 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab092dbd 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.8   0.0% 0x00002aaaab092e02 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab092e47 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab092e8c 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%     19.4   0.6% 0x00002aaaab092f5b 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.1   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09d47d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09d493 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09d7ad 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09d9b9 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09eb2b 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%     16.7   0.5% 0x00002aaaab09ecab 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09f287 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09f29d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.1   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09f771 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab09fd4d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.1   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0a0783 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0a0799 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0a0907 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0a091d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.1   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0a987d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0a9893 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0a9cbd 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aa1a1 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aa1b7 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aa401 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aa417 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.2   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aa581 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      2.2   0.1% 0x00002aaaab0aa597 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aa701 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aa717 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.3   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aafb1 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.2   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0aafc7 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ab1ba 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ab34b 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ab361 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ab5ab 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ab5c1 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ab907 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ab91d 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      2.2   0.1% 0x00002aaaab0c5c00 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.3   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ea7bd 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0ead3c 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0eadfa 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0eaecd 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.3   0.0% 0x00002aaaab0edc3a 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab10ac1c 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab145704 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab187c64 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab36819c 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab3741b3 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab387157 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab39666f 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab4b37e7 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab4e847a 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab505ce8 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%     10.9   0.3% 0x00002aaaab569ce6 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab574e97 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%   3102.7  97.9% 0x00002aaaab601926
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab67fb23 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% 0x00002aaaab7d2075 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% AbstractCompiler::initialize_runtimes 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% AbstractInterpreterGenerator::generate_method_entry 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% AdapterFingerPrint::AdapterFingerPrint 
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0   0.0% AdapterHandlerLibrary::create_native_wrapper
```

The memory of java process kept increasing until use up.

what does "0x00002aaaab601926" mean? How can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like 0x00002aaaab601926 is the address of the allocated object. We cannot tell you how to fix if we don't know what you're doing on the first place...

Comment: simply put: the java software you are running has a memory leak, e.g. a bug or malconfiguration. You need to fix that...